# specify a range for command but not move cursor

Tags: range

In vim, when executing a command with a range specified, the cursor will move to the end of the range. For example, after `10;+4print`, cursor will be at line 14 wherever you run this command.

Q1: Is there a method to hold the cursor while executing this?

In addition, consider a user defined command with range, such as

```
command -range Test call TestFunc(<line1>, <line2>)
function TestFunc(line1, line2)
    echo line('.')
endfunction
```

with line number shown.

Q2. run `:10;+4Test` will have cursor stop at line 10 and the result will has is also 10. This means the function is called after setting the cursor to line 10. The `current line` where the command is executed is not accessible (at least using `line('.')`). How should I get the correct line number in the function?

Comment: Lookup [`winsaveview()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#winsaveview%28%29) and [`winrestview()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#winrestview%28%29)

Comment: That one returns the same line number. It is because before the function gets called, the cursor position is already changed (to `10`)